# Updating Sqlite3 on Centos7 64bit

Tags: centos, sqlite

I need to update Centos7's sqlite version to play nice with python3.

By default Centos7 comes with sqlite 3.7 and I cant overwrite is since Centos7 uses it for other things.

I tried to use [this tutorial](https://linuxhint.com/upgrade-to-latest-sqlite3-on-centos7/) but realized that the sqlite3 that is supplied on the site is 32 bit which doesn't work correctly with my 64-bit system.

I've tried `yum install sqlite3` which returns no package sqlite3available and `yum install sqlite` which returns claims sqlite-3.7 is the latest version (which it isn't).

I'm hesitant to try `yum update sqlite` since I don't want to break dependencies.

How do I do about updating sqlite3 on Centos7 64-bit with out breaking previous dependencies.

Comment: Latest is sqlite~3.31 (Fedora32) : Which version do you want ? .... One app depends on sqlite : `$ rpm -q --whatrequires sqlite` → setools-libs → sqlite => 3.2.0 ... so it seems you can use a later version.

Comment: @KnudLarsen 3.31 would be the best, python 3.7 only requires past 3.8 I believe